# building and pushing a docker image on nexus with concourse

Tags: image, docker, nexus, concourse

I'm working on a concourse pipeline , and I would like to build and push a docker image on Nexus repository, but I can't find a concourse resource to use . I found this Concourse resource **https://github.com/concourse/docker-image-resource** but it's used to push a docker image on a Dockerhub repository with concourse , and that is not what I want.
here is my resource concourse for nexus :

```
- name: nexus
  source:
    artifact: ((nameOfTheJar)):jar
    url: ((nexusUrl))
    username: ((nexusUser))
    password: ((nexusPassword))
    version_file: version/version
  type: maven-resource
```

do you think that we can use it to push a docker image in nexus?
And here is the code to put on my nexus resource

```
- params:
      file: /build/libs/*.jar
      version_file: version/version
    put: nexus
```

I can't find a way to use those two codes for what I want.
does anyone know a Concourse resource that can help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the task defined [here](https://github.com/vito/oci-build-task). It will build your image and output a tar file you could upload to nexus. Of course, if you require a JAR file as your question suggests, you could unpack and repack the tar as a jar in a subsequent task in the same job before uploading.

Comment: Thank you for your response , but does it work with a docker-compose.yml file or not , because I'm using docker-compose.yml file to create my docker image.

Comment: The oci-build-task works in any concourse worker. If you're not using the concourse worker to build your task, it can still be done as it's just an image itself, but I'm unfamiliar with docker-compose and wouldn't be able to recommend how to configured it. I am confident it would work, though.

Comment: okay I'll search for the solution for docker-compose , but can you give me an exemple of the resource that you gave me , but with nexus as the repository for the put. because I did this `
 - name: nexus
  type: registry-image
  source:
    artifact: myService:tar
    url: ((nexusContextUrl))
    username: ((nexusUser))
    password: ((nexusPassword))
    version_file: version/version` and it didn't work

Comment: if you want to use `registry-image`, it needs to look something like this:
    
    - name: nexus
      type: registry-image
      source:
        registry: <your nexus docker url>
        tag: <your tag>
        username: ((nexusUser))
        password: ((nexusPassword))
```

But as you've described it, it may not work since you're not using the docker API that nexus may or may not provide.